# Multiple activites in a TabHost

Tags: android

This code works well for displaying separate xml items in my main.xml. But is there any way to run an activity in each tab? Preferably without extending `TabActivity`, because its deprecated. Or should i use a completely different approach?

Thanks

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost tabs = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.TabHost01);

    tabs.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");

    spec1.setContent(R.id.AnalogClock01);
    spec1.setIndicator("Analog Clock");

    tabs.addTab(spec1);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec2 = tabs.newTabSpec("tag2");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.DigitalClock01);
    spec2.setIndicator("Digital Clock");

    tabs.addTab(spec2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use [`Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)s. There is some sample code in the API Demos that demonstrates the approach (called [`FragmentTabs.java`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabs.java)) but you'll most likely want to read up on [`Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)s before you start, since they were a very important introduction to Android 3.0 and are included in the compatibility package that goes back to Android 1.6.